# Regex for special characters?

Tags: c#, regex

```
string Val = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, @"[^a-z, A-z, 0-9]", string.Empty);
```

This expression does not match the character **^** and **_**. What should i do to match those values?

One more things is, If **TextBox1.Text** string value is more than 10, the last string value(11th string value) should match.

Comment: what are you trying to ask **exactly**..

Comment: for caret you only need to escape it with a backslash `\^` as for the underscode `_` you don't need to escape that and I cannot understand your last question about the string length, care to emphasize??

Comment: This expression @"[^a-z, A-z, 0-9]" would match with all value rest of ^ and _. But i need expression to match these two value.

Comment: if the string value having more than 10 character, the last character should math. I mean, q1q2q1q2q2W here W should match.

Comment: btw: the expression should be `[a-zA-z0-9^_]` without commas and spaces, otherwise spaces and commas would be matched as well.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - except that the "^" belongs at the start to signal that it matches anything BUT letters and digits.

Comment: @HansKesting: Are you sure? The OP want to match "^" and "_". (This is how I understand the question.) It is probably a  coincidence that he uses `^` as first character.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: You have missed (like ASHOK) that he wrote `A-z` and therefore included `^` and `_` in his negated character class.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - The "special characters" from the title seems to conform to a "non-letter/digit" match that seems to be attempted. But you are right, the question itself suggests "^"and "_".

Comment: @ASHOK A: Please specify **exactly** what you want to match! Your question creates a lot of confusion.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Is `A-z` intentional or a typo?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: It's obviously a typo - with the unfortunate consequences that it precludes `^` and `_` from matching because they happen to be in the ASCII range between `Z` and `a`. See my answer.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "if value is more than 10, the 11th value should match"?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the ^ is has special meaning when enclosed in square brackets. It means match everything but those specified in the character class, basically `'[]'`.

If you want to match `"^"` and `"_"`, put the caret `(^)` in another position than after the opening bracket like so, using the repetition to restrict character length:

```
[\W_]
```

That will make sure the characters in the entire string are 10.

Or you escape it using the slash `"\^"`.

```
string Val = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, @"[\W_]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: If i use this expression [^\w], i gt the result. But i want restrict  character length. Only ten character allow. what should i do ?

Comment: @ASHOKA Check my answer, I added the character restriction.

Comment: @Kata: ASHOK is using the negated character class on purpose. He just happens to negate more characters than he thinks. See my answer.

Comment: Uh, your regex only modifies the string (by deleting it) if it consists entirely of unwanted letters (and only if it's less than 1 characters long) - which is not at all what is desired.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Help me understand! My understanding is that he wants to match anything that is not a character, which can be capture with the negated character class "\W", but he also wants to match the underscore "_", which I have explicitly added into the regex? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: He wants to remove all characters besides `A-Z`, `a-z` and `0-9` from the string, so `"ABC^_-abc123"` would become `"ABCabc123"`. His problem was that his regex only changed it to `"ABC^_abc123"`. At least that's my understanding from his question and his comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25473/discussion-between-kata-and-tim-pietzcker)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `A-z`.

This matches all ASCII letters `A` through `Z`, *then the characters that lie between `Z` and `a` (which contain, among others, `^` and `_`)*, then all ASCII letters between `a` and `z`. This means that `^` and `_` won't be matched by your regex (as well as the comma and space which you included in your regex as well).

To clarify, your regex could also have been written as

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\[\\\]^_` ,]
```

You probably wanted

```
string Val = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", string.Empty);
```